# Rabbitmq-server not starting on debian jessie

Tags: rabbitmq, debian-jessie

I have a VPS from digital ocean running jessie. I am trying to install `rabbitmq-server` on the machine but i am not able to start the server.

```
/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start
Starting rabbitmq-server (via systemctl): rabbitmq-server.serviceJob for rabbitmq-server.service failed. See 'systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details. failed!`


systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service
● rabbitmq-server.service - LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2015-10-19 04:36:33 EDT; 2min 33s ago
  Process: 16172 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 19 04:35:22 saltcode.in su[16183]: + ??? root:rabbitmq
Oct 19 04:35:22 saltcode.in su[16183]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user rabbitmq by (uid=0)
Oct 19 04:36:00 saltcode.in su[16236]: Successful su for rabbitmq by root
Oct 19 04:36:00 saltcode.in su[16236]: + ??? root:rabbitmq
Oct 19 04:36:00 saltcode.in su[16236]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user rabbitmq by (uid=0)
Oct 19 04:36:33 saltcode.in rabbitmq-server[16172]: Starting message broker: rabbitmq-serverFAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_\{log, _err\} ... (warning).
Oct 19 04:36:33 saltcode.in rabbitmq-server[16172]: failed!
Oct 19 04:36:33 saltcode.in systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 19 04:36:33 saltcode.in systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by RabbitMQ broker.
Oct 19 04:36:33 saltcode.in systemd[1]: Unit rabbitmq-server.service entered failed state.
```

These are lines from log

```
/var/log/rabbitmq$ tail *
==> startup_err <==

==> startup_log <==
ERROR: epmd error for host saltcode: timeout (timed out)
```

Comment: You should check and probably add the content of `/var/log/rabbitmq/startup_log` and `/var/log/rabbitmq/startup_err `.

Comment: @knowhy I have edited my question

Comment: try editing your `/etc/hosts` and add `saltcode` to the localhost line. You can also try to `ping saltcode`. I guess `saltcode` does not resolv and that is why the init script fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get `ERROR: epmd error for host saltcode: timeout (timed out)` in your rabbitmq startup log it means that your `rabbitmq` instance can't find the [Erland Port Mapper Daemon (epmd)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html). The default port for `epmd` is `4369`.

If you get an `timeout` error in the log you should check if the hostname in the log resolves by running `ping hostname`. If the hostname does not resolve you need to edit the `/etc/hosts` file and add an entry for the host.